# Apache Derby Application with large csv files

Tags: database, csv, derby

I'm designing a data manager that aggregates large CSV files collected from an autonomous underwater vehicle. The time resolution is very fine, so these files get very large for long runs. It collects a lot of parameters, pitch, roll, altitude .. etc. I am investigating the use of an embedded Apache Derby database for this. I have seen that derby can indeed do bulk import of CSV files, but there might be some limitations on the size of the import.

My question is, would an embedded database be well suited for this application? If so, what should I consider when creating tables for this specific kind of data. My experience with databases is limited to a reactivity small amount of persistent data for web applications.

Here is an example of the type of data I am dealing with. They typically are split into multiple files for a single run with around 10,000 lines each and up to 80 columns.

[image: data example]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your question is, but in the past I've imported CSV files into Derby containing upwards of 200,000 lines in the CSV file, with no problems whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks. If you take a look at the image link you can see the type of data I am working with. The idea is to store a large amount of this type of data and have the ability to grab a time frame and plot it. I'm just not sure the best way to approach organizing this type of data. I guess a solution would be creating a table for each run and the rows can be each time (millisecond resolution) that sensors are polled.